# TauDEM in QSWAT fails to creat Stream network

Tags: qgis, taudem, qswat

I am very new at QSWAT. When I try to create streams in QSWAT, after inputing a DEM and specifying the  Threshold, it fails to create the stream network. I get an error message "*** Problem with TauDEM StreamNet: please examine output above. *** "

Any help please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the files were corrupted. That when i recopied the data, the error cleared